# MySql logic to take a Date as an Input and print a Number

Tags: mysql, sql, logic

MySql logic to take a Date as an Input and print the following number - Year in date + Month in date in 2 digits. Ex- 2021-05-10 = 202105. Also, if day in date is greater than 15, print next month in the number. Ex - 2021-05-16 = 202106

Comment: Your question is not clear.  First, the title should be a simple title and the question *in the body*.  Sample data and desired results help.  And you are using only one database, so you should have only one database tag.

Comment: Is it clear now?

Answer (score 0):

This is a way:

```
SELECT CAST(CASE WHEN day(some_date) <= 15 
                 THEN DATE_FORMAT(some_date,'%Y%m')
                 ELSE DATE_FORMAT(DATE_ADD(some_date, INTERVAL 1 MONTH) ,'%Y%m') END 
             AS UNSIGNED)

FROM some_table;
```